IIO expose direct values to the user on Nvidia Jetson
I'm fairly new to the Linux kernel development and very new to IIO,
I'm confused about the IIO interface.
I see that with IIO there are two interfaces for the user:

Expose values in sysfs (done with INDIO_DIRECT_MODE), where each channel can be read/written individually.
Expose buffered values from /dev/iio:deviceN where channels values are packed into a sequence of bytes.

I'm writing a driver on Nvidia Jetson for a mechanical device that can move, in the driver there's a device with two channels:

target position
actual position

I would like to expose those value to the user directly (no need for sampling, just read/write values as the user reads/writes), so something like option (1.) above, but the sysfs files that are created belong to root:root and their permission is 0600.

I am not sure what the exact problem you have. The sysfs files always have permissions available either to root or to more users (as UGO triplets), the ownership doesn’t matter really. And IIRC the IIO provides ABI with permissions 0644 or 0444, so anybody, AKA others in UGO notation) may read them. (UGO stands for User Group Others — it’s very basic UNIX paradigm.)

I found out what happened, at one point Nvidia changed the permissions of sysfs files from S_IRUGO (everybody can read) to S_IRUGO (only user can read), this can be seen in the kernel source in drivers/iio/industrialio-core.c in the function __iio_device_attr_init(). So I will need to change the permissions after the files are created

Your previous comment is unclear because you wrote S_IRUGO twice. I assume you are referring to these lines of code from 2011: if (readfunc) { dev_attr->attr.mode |= S_IRUGO; dev_attr->show = readfunc; } if (writefunc) { dev_attr->attr.mode |= S_IWUSR; dev_attr->store = writefunc; }. Have Nvidia changed the code in their custom kernel? (Note, the constants S_IRUGO etc. have since been replaced with equivalent octal constants such as 0444 in kernel version v6.0.)

File a bug report then to the vendor of the custom Linux kernel. The vanilla has no such an issue AFAIK.

Sorry for the confusion,
I'm using Jetson Linux 35.4.1 which uses kernel 5.10,
Nvidia's change I'm referring to is this one
